# How to add a link href on a HTML element and open in new window in React

Tags: html, reactjs

I am having a banner on my React side.

When clicking the banner it should open in new tab `target: _blank` and go to `href://www.example.com`.

The markup would be something like:

```
<div onClick={// code here?}>
 // Banner markup
</div>
```

What are best practices in React to do this and what should be the HTML attribute to click on?

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
<div onClick={() => window.open('www.example.com.', '_blank')}>
 // Banner markup
</div>
```